# PHP Regex preg_replace to convert youtube URL to embed URL version

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am using preg_replace like this, but having the following issues:

```
$pattern = '#http(s)://(www\.)?youtube\.com/watch\?v=([^ &\n]+)(&.*?(\n|\s))?.+#i';
$replacement = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/$3';
$final = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bf3iBtURGxk');

echo $final;
```

outputs http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bf3iBtURGxk [didn't work at all]

```
$final = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bf3iBtURGxk');

echo $final;
```

outputs http://www.youtube.com/v/Bf3iBtURGx [works! but truncates final character!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pattern = '#https?://(?:www\.)?youtube\.com/watch\?v=([0-9a-z]+)#i';
$replacement = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/$1';
$final = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bf3iBtURGxk'); 
echo $final;
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/199186)

Answer (score 0):

Surrounding a character with `(..)` does not make it optional. That's why the first yrl with `http` protocol does not match. Append `?` to make it optional:

```
http(s) -> http(s)?
```

---

After `v=` cames alphabet and digits. You can use `\w` to match alphabet, digits (`\w` also matches `_`, but not a big problem for this case)

```
$pattern = '#http(s)?://(www\.)?youtube\.com/watch\?v=(\w+)#i';
```